# PHP: Display Minecraft Status using API --> BootStrap

Tags: php, html, css, status, minecraft

I found a simple API to use to get the status of a server, and I am wanting to incorporate those numbers into bootstrap, I tried to do something here, but it isn't displaying the numbers as a "width" in the progress bar.

```
<title>Status</title>

<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <?php
  $data = file_get_contents('http://api.iamphoenix.me/get/?server_ip=mineca.de&clean=true');
  $array = explode(',', $data);

  if($array[0] == 'true') {
 echo 'The server is Online
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar"  role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax='.$array[1].' style='.$array[2].'>
  </div>
</div>';
  } else {
     // This will only be displayed if the server is offline.
    echo '<font color=red>The server is Offline!</font> Please Check back later.';
 }
 ?>
```

Any ways of help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm very far from understanding what minecraft and twitter bootstrap could possibly have in common.

Comment: We're taking the status of the server, whether it be offline and offline, and the amount of players and turning that into a value that could be expressed in progress bar
Example: http://secure.swag-craft.net/mcstatus_v1/index.html

Comment: "Not working" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Comment: Sorry about that, I added more description.

Comment: Getting data from an api and plugging it into an html inline style is one of the funniest things I've ever seen in code. I want to help you, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: And whats the contents of `print_r($array)` ?

Comment: @dbh The API returns something like this: `true,4219,10000,Minecade Network Now Supporting 1.6.4 AND 1.7.2!,1.7.2`

Answer (score 1):

This answer is my understanding of what you want. You need to divide the value returned from the array by 100, and then you can use this for the `width` of the progress bar.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://api.iamphoenix.me/get/?server_ip=mineca.de&clean=true');
$array = explode(',', $data);

if($array[0] == 'true') {
    echo 'The server is Online
    <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: '.($array[1] / 100).'%">
    </div>
    </div>';
} else {
    // This will only be displayed if the server is offline.
    echo '<font color=red>The server is Offline!</font> Please Check back later.';
}
?>
```

Comment: The amount of players or division is determined by the `$array[2]`